# Angular 5: entry components in lazy module with dynamic route

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, routes, lazy-evaluation

Using Ng 5.1.3, CLI 1.6.3  which is the most up to date as of this post.

Currently I am stuck. I have a situation where I am loading a page that requires a different router footprint for mobile versus desktop views. This view currently is in a lazy loaded module. I created two different landing view pages and thought I could create two different routing configs while have my router switch between the routing configs based on the screen width. This works on eagerly loaded components, but not lazy loaded ones in a module. The resetConfig command off the router requires those components used in that route to be set as entry components, but the router doesn't see lazy components placed in the entrycomponent section of their lazy module. Here is the plunker example code of what I have going on:

https://embed.plnkr.co/CA96WEk5qgJwghEbyBF8/

I left the plunker in working state, but the problem occurs when trying to use the same resolution routing switching in the lazy module as done with the eager components. In the lazy/lazy.module.ts file change the routing imported from the lazyRouting object to the LazyRoutingModule instead. An error generates for not having the lazy components as part of the NgMoule.entryComponents object.

Below is code snippets of the parts in question

resolution service code:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ResolutionService {
  constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
    // On resize
    window.onresize = (e) => {
      ngZone.run(() => {
        this.width.next(window.innerWidth);
      });
    };
  }

  width: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(window.innerWidth);

  getWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

routing module code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListDesktopComponent } from './components/index';
import { ListMobileComponent } from './components/index';
import { ValueDesktopComponent } from './components/index';
import { ValueMobileComponent } from './components/index';

import { ResolutionService } from './shared/index';

export const appDesktopRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListDesktopComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: ValueDesktopComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'lazy',
    loadChildren: './app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
  }
];

export const appMobileRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ListMobileComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ValueMobileComponent
  },
  { path: 'lazy',
    loadChildren: './app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  private previousWidth: number;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private resolutionService: ResolutionService
  ) {
    this.previousWidth = -999;

    resolutionService.width.subscribe(width => {
      this.doReRoute(width);
    });
  }

  doReRoute(width: number) {
    const MOBILE_WIDTH = 500; // magic number resolution breakpoint
    if (width !== this.previousWidth) {
      if (width < MOBILE_WIDTH && (this.previousWidth >= MOBILE_WIDTH || this.previousWidth === -999)) {
        this.router.resetConfig(appMobileRoutes);
        this.router.navigate([]);
      } else if (width >= MOBILE_WIDTH && this.previousWidth < MOBILE_WIDTH) {
        this.router.resetConfig(appDesktopRoutes);
        this.router.navigate([]);
      }
      this.previousWidth = width;
    }
  }
}
```

That is for the main app routing, but the lazy module is the same. Just took the eager components and duplicated them to be part of a lazy module. The above works for eager components as part of the main module, but not for lazy modules.

If I look at the componentfactoryresolver object, the entry components for my lazy module end up as a child array in that object instead of being part of the main parent array. I'm a little stumped as how to get the router using resetConfig to use the entry components found in the lazy module instead of the main app module. Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Could you include the code in the question instead of as a link?

Comment: editted in the major parts of the code in question that is having the problem from the plunker example.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a suitable solution that I really liked. I ended up having to go with a mobile and desktop landing page setup with a router URL that swapped between the pages based on the resolution. It's not elegant, but it works for now. Hoping that the angular team adds dynamic route changing to lazy loaded modules in the future because as far as I can tell it doesn't work that way now.